# How to get error code from a subshell run within eval

Tags: bash, environment-variables, eval, status, subshell

I have tried looking for a questions similar to this that cover a solution for me, but none that I could find quite answer my exact question.

I would like to run a command within a subshell within an eval call and obtain the status code returned by the function called within the subshell.

For example, I call a command like this:

```
eval "$(some_command)"
if [ "${?}" -ne 0 ]
then
    # do stuff if `some_command` returned status code not equal to zero
fi
```

This `some_command` function returns a list of environment variables and their assignments like this:

```
$ some_command      # Execute some_command in a standard fashion without eval or subshell
some_env_variable='some_value'
another_env_variable='another value'
```

The goal is to run this single command to add these environment variable to the current environment. The only way to do that is to call `some_command` within a subshell, and have eval evaluate the resulting output. If I do this without the subshell, eval will simply run `some_command` but it will not evaluate it's output to add the environment variable to the current environment.

This works:

```
$ eval "some_command"
-bash: some_command: command not found
$ echo $?
127
```

This works:

```
$ $(some_command)
-bash: some_command: command not found
$ echo $?
127
```

But this does not work:

```
$ eval "$(some_command)"
-bash: some_command: command not found
$ echo $?
0
```

There must be some way of obtaining the resulting status code from some_command, but I have been unable to determine how. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If I understand your question, the [bash(1) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) is clear "The args are read and concatenated together into a single command. This command is then read and executed by the shell, and its **exit status** is returned as the value of  eval. If there are no args, or only null arguments, eval returns 0."

Comment: Maybe there's a way to avoid `eval` entirely?

Comment: I know many developers are very weary of using eval because it is "dangerous" or whatever, but this is definitely what I would like to do. I have extensive verification that the output of some_command will not be dangerous for eval to interpret. I need to use eval because I would like the output of some_command to add environment variables to the calling process

Comment: @PaulHodges This is the one situation where `eval` is pretty much indispensable; you do have to trust the program to produce output that is safe to evaluate. `ssh-agent` is a commonly used example where it is designed to be used with `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are actually concerned about the exit status, don't use `eval` immediately.

```
if envvars=$(some_command); then
    eval "$envvars"
else
    # do something else
fi
```

If you need the exact error code, instead of just distinguishing between 0 and non-zero:

```
envvars=$(some_command)
rv=$?  # save it for later if necessary
case $rv in
   0) eval "$envvars" ;;
   1) ... ;;
   2) ... ;;
   # etc
   *) printf 'Some other error %d\n' "$rv" >&2 ;;
esac
```

Comment: This will work for determining whether the command succeeded or not, but still does not give me the actual status code within an environment variable such as `$?`. I'd like to be able to grab the error code and preform certain actions based on the exact value of the status code.

Comment: `$?` should be available in the `else` block.

Comment: @IanTait The question just says that you want to do something if the status is not `0`, it doesn't say you need to distinguish different codes.

Comment: It says that I want to capture the status code. From the original post: "I would like to run a command within a subshell within an eval call and OBTAIN THE STATUS CODE returned by the function called within the subshell". I have made some edits to try to make this more clear.

Comment: It also says `# do stuff if \`some_command\` returned status code not equal to zero`

Comment: Yes, you have to take the entire post into consideration to determine what I am trying to achieve. Simply looking at one line will not do.

Comment: @chepner After your edit, that will work for me. After looking at it, it seems obvious to me.. I was stuck in a one-liner mindset and I just needed to get away from that. Thanks!